# Function which returns the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation

Tags: python, swift, numpy, math, matrix

I have been trying to rewrite the code from Python to Swift but I'm stuck on the function which should return the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. Does anyone know a library written in Swift which has an equivalent method to the **[`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)**? I'd be grateful for your help.

Python code:

```
a = numpy.array([[p2.x-p1.x,p2.y-p1.y],[p4.x-p3.x,p4.y-p3.y],[p4.x-p2.x,p4.y-p2.y],[p3.x-p1.x,p3.y-p1.y]])
b = numpy.array([number1,number2,number3,number4])
res = numpy.linalg.lstsq(a,b) 
result = [float(res[0][0]),float(res[0][1])]
return result
```

Swift code so far:

```
var matrix1 = [[p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y],[p4.x-p3.x, p4.y-p3.y], [p4.x-p2.x, p4.y-p2.y], [p3.x-p1.x, p3.y-p1.y]]
var matrix2 = [number1, number2, number3, number4]
```

Comment: Add the code here! Can't help without code.

Comment: The [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/) includes the [BLAS library](http://www.netlib.org/blas/faq.html) which has functions for [Linear Least Squares Problems](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html). Using these functions from Swift requires some work though :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no method which solves LLS problems.

Comment: Isn't DGELS (or one of its variations) what you need?

Comment: Could you mention the formula used to calculate least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation?

Comment: With some caveats, but if you have an overdetermined system of `n` equations in 2 variables, i.e. if your problem can be written as `A * x = b`, with `A` having shape `(n, 2)`, `x` shape `(2,)` and `b` shape `(n,)`, then the least squares solution is the same as the solution of the equivalent `A.T * A * x = A.T * b`, and since `A.T * A` has shape `(2, 2)` and `A.T * b` has shape `(2,)`, you have a very simple system that can easily be solved, e.g. using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). It should be very simple to write that from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Accelerate framework included the [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/index.html) linear algebra package,
which has a [DGELS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga1df516c81d3e902cca1fc79a7220b9cb.html#ga1df516c81d3e902cca1fc79a7220b9cb) function to solve under- or overdetermined linear systems. From the documentation:

> DGELS solves overdetermined or underdetermined real linear systems
>    involving an M-by-N matrix A, or its transpose, using a QR or LQ
>    factorization of A.  It is assumed that A has full rank.

Here is an example how that function can be used from Swift.
It is essentially a translation of [this C sample code](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgels_ex.c.htm).

```swift
func solveLeastSquare(A A: [[Double]], B: [Double]) -> [Double]? {
    precondition(A.count == B.count, "Non-matching dimensions")

    var mode = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(ascii: "N")) // "Normal" mode
    var nrows = CInt(A.count)
    var ncols = CInt(A[0].count)
    var nrhs = CInt(1)
    var ldb = max(nrows, ncols)

    // Flattened columns of matrix A
    var localA = (0 ..< nrows * ncols).map {
        A[Int($0 % nrows)][Int($0 / nrows)]
    }

    // Vector B, expanded by zeros if ncols > nrows
    var localB = B
    if ldb > nrows {
        localB.appendContentsOf([Double](count: ldb - nrows, repeatedValue: 0.0))
    }

    var wkopt = 0.0
    var lwork: CInt = -1
    var info: CInt = 0

    // First call to determine optimal workspace size
    dgels_(&mode, &nrows, &ncols, &nrhs, &localA, &nrows, &localB, &ldb, &wkopt, &lwork, &info)
    lwork = Int32(wkopt)

    // Allocate workspace and do actual calculation
    var work = [Double](count: Int(lwork), repeatedValue: 0.0)
    dgels_(&mode, &nrows, &ncols, &nrhs, &localA, &nrows, &localB, &ldb, &work, &lwork, &info)

    if info != 0 {
        print("A does not have full rank; the least squares solution could not be computed.")
        return nil
    }
    return Array(localB.prefix(Int(ncols)))
}
```

Some notes:

- `dgels_()` modifies the passed matrix and vector data, and expects
  the matrix as "flat" array containing the columns of `A`.
  Also the right-hand side is expected as an array with length `max(M, N)`.
  For this reason, the input data is copied to local variables first.
- All arguments must be passed by reference to  `dgels_()`, that's why
  they are all stored in `var`s.
- A C integer is a 32-bit integer, which makes some conversions between
  `Int` and `CInt` necessary.

**Example 1:** Overdetermined system, from http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/ls.pdf.

```
let A = [[ 2.0, 0.0 ],
         [ -1.0, 1.0 ],
         [ 0.0, 2.0 ]]
let B = [ 1.0, 0.0, -1.0 ]
if let x = solveLeastSquare(A: A, B: B) {
    print(x) // [0.33333333333333326, -0.33333333333333343]
}
```

**Example 2:** Underdetermined system, minimum norm
solution to `x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1.0`.

```
let A = [[ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]]
let B = [ 1.0 ]
if let x = solveLeastSquare(A: A, B: B) {
    print(x) // [0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333337]
}
```

---

Update for **Swift 3** and **Swift 4:**

```
func solveLeastSquare(A: [[Double]], B: [Double]) -> [Double]? {
    precondition(A.count == B.count, "Non-matching dimensions")

    var mode = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(ascii: "N")) // "Normal" mode
    var nrows = CInt(A.count)
    var ncols = CInt(A[0].count)
    var nrhs = CInt(1)
    var ldb = max(nrows, ncols)

    // Flattened columns of matrix A
    var localA = (0 ..< nrows * ncols).map { (i) -> Double in
        A[Int(i % nrows)][Int(i / nrows)]
    }

    // Vector B, expanded by zeros if ncols > nrows
    var localB = B
    if ldb > nrows {
        localB.append(contentsOf: [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: Int(ldb - nrows)))
    }

    var wkopt = 0.0
    var lwork: CInt = -1
    var info: CInt = 0

    // First call to determine optimal workspace size
    var nrows_copy = nrows // Workaround for SE-0176
    dgels_(&mode, &nrows, &ncols, &nrhs, &localA, &nrows_copy, &localB, &ldb, &wkopt, &lwork, &info)
    lwork = Int32(wkopt)

    // Allocate workspace and do actual calculation
    var work = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: Int(lwork))
    dgels_(&mode, &nrows, &ncols, &nrhs, &localA, &nrows_copy, &localB, &ldb, &work, &lwork, &info)

    if info != 0 {
        print("A does not have full rank; the least squares solution could not be computed.")
        return nil
    }
    return Array(localB.prefix(Int(ncols)))
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you!