# Solving System of Equations in Swift

Tags: swift, matrix

I want to replicate in Swift what the "\" (backslash) operator does in Matlab.

Essentially, it solves a set of equations in Matrix form to give coefficients (solution).

Matrix A is given as follows:

```
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     4     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     4     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     4     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     4     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     4     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     4     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     4     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     4     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Matrix b is given as follows:

```
 0
-15
-15
-3
-3
45
-12
-6
 0
 0
```

Operation cj = A\b in Matlab gives:

```
0
-2.9185
-3.3259
1.2220
-4.5620
14.0262
-6.5427
0.1447
-0.0362
0
```

How do I implement the above in Swift?

The swift equivalent Matrices/Arrays are:

```
let A = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

let b = [0, -15, -15, -3, -3, 45, -12, -6, 0, 0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Swift* has no functions to solve equations, but the Accelerate framework includes the LAPACK linear algebra package ...

Comment: Here is a similar question, that might help as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836311/function-which-returns-the-least-squares-solution-to-a-linear-matrix-equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know much about MATLAB, but `A\b` seems to return the solution of AX=B. For such purpose, you can use `la_solve` in LinearAlgebra framework (Accelerate.vecLib.LinearAlgebra) in iOS/macOS.

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate.vecLib.LinearAlgebra

let A: [Double] = [
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
let matA = la_matrix_from_double_buffer(A, 10, 10, 10, la_hint_t(LA_NO_HINT), la_attribute_t(LA_DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES))

let b: [Double] = [
    0, -15, -15, -3, -3, 45, -12, -6, 0, 0
]
let vecB = la_matrix_from_double_buffer(b, 10, 1, 1, la_hint_t(LA_NO_HINT), la_attribute_t(LA_DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES))

let vecCj = la_solve(matA, vecB)
var cj: [Double] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 10)

let status = la_matrix_to_double_buffer(&cj, 1, vecCj)
if status == la_status_t(LA_SUCCESS) {
    print(cj) //->[0.0, -2.9185349611542728, -3.3258601553829079, 1.2219755826859044, -4.5620421753607099, 14.026193118756936, -6.5427302996670358, 0.14472807991120964, -0.036182019977802411, 0.0]
} else {
    print("Failure: \(status)")
}
```

The result seems to be the same (other than the precision) as yours.

Comment: This has magically solved my problem / equations -- thanks so much OOper ! Wherever you used 10, I replaced with "la_count_t(n)" since "var n = xi.count" is 10 in this case. Thanks again !

Comment: I have quick Q OOper: Is there a count or size limit to la_solve? I notice when I have big matrices (say with 16000) elements for large arrays (signals), I get Malloc (memory allocation) errors. To overcome this, I break long arrays in chunks of 1000 samples and then analyze them sequentially, finally appending all results. Is this a good approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542256/how-to-make-cubic-spline-interpolation-algorithm-faster/41543052#41543052

Comment: @Saif, the doc of `la_solve` (see Quick Help of Xcode) does not say anything about size limitations. But generally, defining a matrix of 16000 x 16000 elements seems not to be practical in iOS. If your matrix A must always be tridiagonal, as shown in the other thread, LAPACK has some functions specific for tridiagonal matrices which consumes only O(N) memory space and may be far more efficient than using general algorithm. Check [LAPACK `dgtsv`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html-3.4.2/d4/d62/group__double_g_tsolve.html#). In Swift, `import Accelerate.vecLib.clapack` and `dgtsv_(...)`.

Comment: Thanks OOPer. I did look into this. But there are no examples that I could try. As I am fairly new to SWIFT, I am struggling to pass the 8 input parameters the function asks for. Is there an example somewhere?

Comment: I found and implemented this example (looks part of LAPACK): http://connor-johnson.com/2015/10/17/solving-linear-equations-with-swift-and-accelerate/. Again I get error (when run on iPhone): Having Fun 4(1398,0x1b0a10c40) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=2217787392) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: The article you have found uses LU factorization based algorithm and consumes O(N^2) memory. You need to find an example using `dgtsv_` or `sgtsv_`. Better start a new thread.

Comment: Thanks man, it was A[good] solution, but now it's deprecated. "'la_matrix_from_double_buffer' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: This API is deprecated, please use BLAS and LAPACK"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but after a day of tries and mistakes to solve system of equations in Swift I found next solution for my data (the result was verified by real algorithm from Math-lab )
The data are:

var matrix:[[Double]] (43,43)

var vector: [Double] (43)

```
func solveSystemOfEquations(matrix:[[Double]], vector:[Double])->[Double]{

    let flatMatrix = Array(matrix.joined())
    let laMatrix:la_object_t =
        la_matrix_from_double_buffer(flatMatrix,  la_count_t(matrix.count),  la_count_t(matrix[0].count),  la_count_t(matrix[0].count), la_hint_t(LA_NO_HINT), la_attribute_t(LA_DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES))
    let laVector = la_matrix_from_double_buffer(vector, la_count_t(vector.count), 1, 1, la_hint_t(LA_NO_HINT), la_attribute_t(LA_DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES))
    let vecCj = la_solve(laMatrix, laVector)
    var result: [Double] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: matrix.count)
    let status = la_matrix_to_double_buffer(&result, 1, vecCj)

    if status == la_status_t(LA_SUCCESS) {
       return result
    } else {
       return [Double]()
    }
}
```

Hope this will helps  :)))