# Swift 4: Pass multidimensional array to c++

Tags: c++, swift, swift4

I have next function in c++:

```
double* solveSystemOfEquatationWithAugmentedMatrix(double **matrix, size_t rows)
```

On the swift part I have simple `[[Double]]` that have to passed

I`ve tried next conversation:

```
let array = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>>.allocate(capacity: matrix.count)
```

The I`ve tried to run over each inner pointer and allocate capacity for each inner pointer, but no luck... there is even no allocate function in each inner row.

What is elegant and fast way to do such conversation and pass to c++?

Comment: This might sound a bit strange but if you are talking about 16 floats (a 4x4 matrix) then I suggest you simply create a 16 parameter function.

Comment: My matrix size various from 43*43 to 15560*15560. May be my c++ function written not right too. Will glad to help with this. I broke my head with this bridging

Comment: Well there is a solution to this or at least it should be. But doing this in Swift hardly seems appropriate... I mean I expect [[Double]] in swift is on stack but having 15kx15k values is most likely not. I would suggest you then rather build this in ObjectiveC and create bridging to swift where you expose values you need.

Comment: I`ve tried to use Accelerate built in framework of swift, but it takes to much time, 10-12 sec, in the worst case to solve, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662099/556526. Also I used LAPACK DGESV, but no luck. Have no idea how to increase it

Comment: Yes I agree this should be done in C. But it might be easiest to bridge to ObjectiveC and then to Swift... Let me show you an example...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be best to create an ObjectiveC wrapper around your matrix buffer. This way you will have access directly to its memory and still be able to use it in swift.

You will need to use your header to control what access you need to the class but here is an example:

```
    @interface Matrix : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, readonly) int rowCount;
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) int columnCount;

    - (double)elementAt:(int)row column:(int)column;
    - (void)setElementAt:(int)row column:(int)column to:(double)value;
    - (instancetype)initWithRowCount:(int)rowCount columnCount:(int)columnCount;

    @end

So we have a basic constructor which accepts number of rows and number of columns as an input. You might actually need only one parameter. And the implementation:

#import "Matrix.h"

@interface Matrix ()

@property (nonatomic) double *buffer;
@property (nonatomic) double *solvedBuffer; // Not sure what this is and how you wish to serve it

@property (nonatomic) int rowCount;
@property (nonatomic) int columnCount;

@end

@implementation Matrix

- (void)dealloc {
    [self freeBuffer];
}

- (instancetype)initWithRowCount:(int)rowCount columnCount:(int)columnCount {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.rowCount = rowCount;
        self.columnCount = columnCount;
        [self generateBuffer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (double)elementAt:(int)row column:(int)column {
    return self.buffer[column*self.rowCount + row];
}

- (void)setElementAt:(int)row column:(int)column to:(double)value {
    self.buffer[column*self.rowCount + row] = value;
}

- (void)generateBuffer {
    if(self.rowCount > 0 && self.columnCount > 0) {
        int size = sizeof(CGFloat)*self.rowCount*self.columnCount;
        self.buffer = malloc(size);
        memset(self.buffer, 0, size); // Set it all to zero
    }
}

- (void)freeBuffer {
    if(self.buffer) {
        free(self.buffer);
        self.buffer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)solveSystem {
    self.solvedBuffer = solveSystemOfEquatationWithAugmentedMatrix((double **)self.buffer, self.rowCount);
}

@end
```

Nothing special really. We have access to buffer, ability to generate it and need to release it manually when done.

I added the "solve system" method which I am not sure what you expect as an output so you will need to create interface for it on your own.

Anyway, if this is an Xcode project you simply create a new file and select to be ObjectiveC. Xcode will ask you to create a bridging header which you need to confirm. Then find this bridging header and add `#import "Matrix.h"` or whatever your file names will be and this object will be available to you in Swift. As for the C part you can see all should be pretty straight forward. IF you really need to expose C++ then simply rename your `Matrix.m` to `Matrix.mm` and Xcode should do the rest for you.

Please also be careful if your matrix should be column or row major. The access may change to `self.buffer[row*self.columnCount + column]` in the other case in 2 methods.